# PDOのLIMITでエラー

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

以下のコードを書きましたが、エラーになってしまいます。
$maxResultと$pageにはデータが入っていることが確認できています。さらに、パラメータを指定せずにリクエストを送るとデータを取得できます。どこが間違っているかわかりますか? よろしくお願いします。

```
if(isset($_GET['maxResult']))
  $maxResult = $_GET['maxResult'];
if(isset($_GET['page']))
  $page = $_GET['page'];
$st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `hogehoge` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT :page, :limit");
$st->bindValue(":page", $page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$st->bindValue(":limit", $maxResult, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if($st->execute()){
  echo json_encode($st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}else{
  sendError("failure");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以前同じ挙動でハマった事がありますが、LIMIT句へのバインドは整数型でなければならなかったはずです。
PDO::PARAM_INTも必要ですが、$_GETや$_POSTで取得したパラメータは文字列として変数に格納されますので、

bindValue(":page", (int)$page, PDO::PARAM_INT)やintvalを使って整数型へキャストさせると取得出来るかと思われます。